Laravel Shopify Package Exception: "Not Found" on API Request Shopify App development kyon147/laravel-shopify
I'm encountering an issue while using the kyon147/laravel-shopify package (version 19.2.0) for developing a Shopify app in Laravel. When attempting to make a request using the doRequest() method in ApiHelper.php, I'm consistently receiving a 404 Not Found response. Here's the debug information I've gathered:
array:7 [
  "errors" => true
  "response" => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response 
  "status" => 404
  "body" => "Not Found"
  "link" => null
  "exception" => GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException {#1421 ▼
    #message: """
      Client error: `POST https://quickstart-18f4d64b.myshopify.com/admin/application_charges/32843137333/activate.json` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
      {"errors":"Not Found"}
      """
    #code: 404
    #file: "vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php"
    #line: 113
    -request: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request 
    -response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#1417 ▶}
    -handlerContext: []
    trace: {▶}
  }
  "timestamps" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 1.71811346076E+15
  ]
]

It seems like the request is failing at the following endpoint:
POST https://store-id.myshopify.com/admin/application_charges/32843137333/activate.json
I've already checked the credentials and endpoints, and they seem correct.
Additional Information:

Laravel version: [10.14.1]
PHP version: [8.2.18]


A 404 error means that the URL doesn't exist. This sounds like more of a question for the package developer. I suggest you ask them through their GitHub page (https://github.com/Kyon147/laravel-shopify)
